# Trivial normal bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology

I would like to know if there is a theorem along those lines: let $V$ be a submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $V$ is the boundary of a submanifold with boundary $W$. Then, the normal bundle of $V$ is trivial.Maybe there are conditions of dimension or orientability for the statment to be true?

The paradigmatic exemple I have in mind is the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ see as the boundary of the closed ball $B^n$ but I would like to know if there is a general pattern behind that.

Comment: The normal bundle of the boundary in a manifold with boundary is trivial. Hence the normal bundle of $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ splits of a trivial bundle. Thus if $V$ has codimension $1$ your claim is clearly true.